# How do I get the integer value of a Hex String

Tags: java

I have this code below:

```
try {
  MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  byte[] byteArray = md.digest(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString((byteArray[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
  }

  int n = (int) Long.parseLong(sb.toString());
  System.out.println(n);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

For some reason I keep getting the output:

`For input string: "4739c5c11d833bb199c16ff95a92b267"`

When no where in this code do I have this `print` statement...

I am trying to get the int value of the Hex String above and I have no clue what is happening.

Comment: Also the `myString` variable value is `123445`

Comment: use `Long.parseLong("123445", 16)` convert Hex string to int / long. In your case, the value of `md5` is too long too be stored by int or long.

Comment: That information should better be in the question directly. Next time put up a full [mcve], including the full exception message /stack trace.

Comment: Sorry about not including that in the original example.

Comment: you can use `new BigIneger(str, 16)`

Comment: Final side note: you want to use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer for such situations. StringBuffer is synchronized, thus you get a performance hit that isn't required unless you are really working the same buffer with multiple threads.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for pointing that out. Performance wasn't an issue here so I didn't take into account that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an md5 hash of your input string.

That hash is that 47.... value!

And that value is by far too large to fit into a long or int variable! Thus you get an exception, and the catch block kicks in.

Long story short: step back and re-think what this method is supposed to do. As it simply can't work this way.

Beyond that: when parsing a hex string, you have to use

```
parseLong(input, 16)
```

In order to tell java that we'll, it should expect a hex number.

My gut feeling here: you are overburdening yourself. You are missing knowledge of very basic Java language elements, but yet you intend to work with advanced concepts  such as a MessageDigest.

Edit: given your comment: read about the BigInteger class. That one provides the means to hold arbitrary large whole numbers.

Comment: The hash with `47...` is a 128 bit value. I need to convert that to a numeric value (not a String which it is right now) and mod it by 4 to get a number between `0 - 3`. Is there no way I can do that? Should I use a different hash algorithm? And yes your gut feeling is pretty accurate. I have a school project I need to do this for. Professor said to use MD5 hash and mod it by 4 to get a number between 0 - 3.

Comment: See my updates. You should not use long then, but the BigInteger class.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. I just did `System.out.println(newBigInteger(sb.toString(), 16).mod(new BigInteger("3")));` It has worked now.

Comment: Btw: when you want to have some real fun, do some research on "computing mod 3 efficiently".

Comment: Definitely will when I get a chance :). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

That output comes from printing the exception's message in the catch block.

The exception is thrown because the number you are trying to parse is too large to fit in the `long` data type.